# Javascript ArrayBuffer to a File on the server side

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have been working on a fileupload which can take in various file types(pdf, image, txt, xls...) using XMLHttpRequest. I am using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer to read the file, append to a FormData before i send it to the server. On the server side, i try to get the InputStream but it seems to be empty. When i try request.getParameter("file"), it seems to return the bytes constructed from the file. How can i convert byte stream to a file back on the server side without the input stream.

```
function processFile(file)
{
    var url = <url>;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData()
    xhr.open('POST', url, true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.onloadend = function(event)
    {
        if (event.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE)
        {
            var byteArray = [];
            var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
            for (var i = 0; i < uint8Array.length; i++)
            {
                byteArray.push(uint8Array[i]);
            }
            fd.append("file",byteArray);
            xhr.send(fd);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java !== Javascript

Comment: "*I am using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer to read the file*" - why? You can just put the file object directly into the `FormData`. Also there's no reason to copy the numbers from the `Uint8Array` into that `byteArray`.

Comment: Thank you Bergi. I will also need to send the meta data on the file like file name, file size and the file type. I can append all of the information on the form data. My question is, how do i process the data i send on the servlet and reconstruct the file. Any sample code would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.